# Set component props as optional in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

so I am trying to make my **label** props as an optional. So If I don't pass **label** props, its default value is false. I keep on getting the following error :
`Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #2 [ <required> $type ]] in class App\View\Components\Form\BaseFormInput`

Here's my code :

`index.blade.php`

```
<x-form.base-form-input :label="true" name="category" placeholder="Kategori" />
```

`base-form-input.blade.php`

```
@props([
    'type' => 'text',
    'placeholder' => '',
    'label' => false,
])

<div class="form-group">

    @if ($label)
    <label for="name" class="text-primary fw-bold">{{ $name }}</label>
    @endif
    <input type="{{ $type }}" class="form-control" {{ $attributes->merge(['class']) }} id="{{ $name }}" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="{{ $placeholder }}" name="{{ $name }}">
</div>
```

`BaseFormInput.php`

```
class BaseFormInput extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $name;
    public $placeholder;
    public $type;
    public $label;
    public function __construct($name, $placeholder, $type, $label)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->placeholder = $placeholder;
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->label = $label;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Closure|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.form.base-form-input');
    }
}
```

I have tried doing `<x-form-input :label="true"/>` but it still doesnt work. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel expects all four parameters `($name, $placeholder, $type, and $label)` to be provided when the BaseFormInput component is instantiated, but when you don't provide them, Laravel throws this error.
Change your `BaseFormInput`:

```
class BaseFormInput extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $placeholder;
    public $type;
    public $label;

    public function __construct($name, $placeholder = '', $type = 'text', $label = false)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->placeholder = $placeholder;
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->label = $label;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.form.base-form-input');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to pass default value to the construct ?

```php
public function __construct($name, $placeholder, $type = 'text', $label)
```